# module 'face_client' has no attribute 'FaceClient'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я установил модуль face_client.
пишу:

```
import face_client
client = face_client.FaceClient(key,secret)
```

Мне выдаёт ошибку - **module 'face_client' has no attribute 'FaceClient'**, хотя сама среда мне подсказывает на этот аттрибут и модуль виден через help("modules").Что я делаю не так?

Модуль на github: https://github.com/SkyBiometry/python-face-client

Comment: Модуля face_client не существует для третьего питона

Comment: @andreymal я его на гитхабе взял - это api сайта

Comment: @Anton ссылку на гитхаб добавьте тогда.

Comment: @Anton кстати, ваш скрипт не face_client.py случайно называется?

Comment: @Anton гитхаб никак не мешает ему не существовать для третьего питона

Comment: @insolor https://github.com/SkyBiometry/python-face-client/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: @Anton, как у вас файл скрипта называется? Если face_client.py - просто переименуйте его, и все заработает.

Comment: @insolor называется по другому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фактически данный модуль не полностью совместим с Python3.

Заглянем в [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/SkyBiometry/python-face-client/blob/master/face_client/__init__.py):

```
__version__ = (1, 2, 'dev')

from face_client import *
```

Для Python3 импорт в этом файле должен выглядеть так:

```
from .face_client import *
```

Тогда код из вашего вопроса увидит класс `FaceClient`.

Как костыль можно у себя в коде поменять импорт на такой:

```
from face_client import face_client
client = face_client.FaceClient(key,secret)
```

Но не факт, что не вылезет еще какая-нибудь несовместимость с Python3.

Comment: вот костылём заработало, но теперь при отправке файла на сервер вылетает ошибка с модулем multiport

Comment: я установил версию питона 2.7 но он не хочет устанавливать этот модуль, пишет не соответствует требованиям

Comment: @Anton ну значит нужно фиксить, отправлять пулл-реквесты

Comment: @Anton, сейчас установил Python 2.7.13, пакет успешно на него установился.

Comment: Кстати, попробуйте этот форк, тут вроде поддержку Python3 допиливали: https://github.com/FrankTheDevop/python-face-client . Правда импорт все равно через "костыльный" вариант.

Comment: т.е. у них на сайте ссылка на старую версию весит?

Comment: я установил версию 2.7 питона и вроде пока нормально работает без ошибок

Comment: @Anton, у них ссылка на свою версию, где поддержка Python3 не доделана. Но т.к. это open source, то никто не мешает стороннему разработчику сделать форк и внести свои изменения, потом предложить их первоначальным разработчикам (это называется pull request).

Comment: @insolod спасибо за помощь

Comment: «Но не факт, что не вылезет еще какая-нибудь несовместимость с Python3» — [таки вылезла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898448), но автор не очень хочет это понимать